# Thunderbird Moved Emails

Tags: thunderbird, exchange

I have an Exchange account setup in Thunderbird using IMAP.  Whenever I move emails from one folder to another, those emails get moved in Thunderbird but when I check webmail (OWA), the messages are still in the same folder and won't move until I restart Thunderbird. Does anyone know a way so it can sync the email move between folders instantly? Thank you.